# consequences of changing a Service Worker directory?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, web-push, service-worker-events, service-worker-config

as you might already know, you should put your service workers inside the base directory so that it has the scope of the whole project, otherwise some features (e.g. navigator.serviceWorker.ready()) won't be available.

My problem is that I've initially put my service worker inside a directory and now I feel kinda trapped.

I use the service worker to register and handle web push notifications and I'm wondering if I would lose all my current subscriptions if I move it to the base directory

N.B. It's mandatory that the service worker registered will remain the same, no new service worker should be registered

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to move your service worker in base directory. You can use "Service-Worker-Allowed" header in your response. If this header is present then your service worker will be registered even if your sw.js file is in nested directory.

```
Service-Worker-Allowed header '/'
```

here the the official documentation regarding this header.

https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#service-worker-allowed

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, I was aware of this header but my concern is about it registering a new service worker or not. Notifications subscriptions are bound to a service worker, therefore if modifying the scope and the headers would cause the registration of a new service worker, it wouldn’t be worth it. If it’s just going to perform an update of the service worker as it would with any other change of it, then it could work

Comment: Unless or until you modified the scope of the service worker, you are good. Header will be only used for registration of service worker nothing else. On top of that you can programmatically control all your service worker status.